# How to create a probability distribution function for a given set of data

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

I was wondering how to create a probability distribution function for the following data.

```
    Data      Probability 
    0-45         0.01
    45-90        0.01
    90-135       0.20        
    135-180      0.01
    180-225      0.10
    225-270      0.60
    270-315      0.01
    315-360      0.06
```

I have read a lot of articles online but unable to find one which solves my problem, most of them work through very simple examples and normally you are given the `pdf`.

I think I have supplied enough information if not please let me know and I will edit to add more information.

Thanks for your time and any help you may be able to offer

Comment: So far what you've said is that the probability of choosing $x$ such that $0 \le x \le 45$ is $0.01$, i.e. $\rm{Pr}(0\le x\le45)=0.01$, and so on for $x > 45$. You haven't assigned any probabilities to values of $x$ within each category. From what you've said, a  value of $x$ in the range $10$ to $12$ might be more likely than a value of $x$ in the range $13$ to $15$, for example. Are you interested in individual values of $x$ and if so are they equally likely?

Answer (score 1):

A probability distribution assigns some probability to a space of outcomes.

In your case the set of all possible values is finite hence a **discrete distribution.** You can write your probability distributions in a more compact fashion as follows:

$$
p(0\le x\le 45)=p(45\le x<90)=p(135\le x\le 180)=p(180\le x\le 225)=p(270\le x \le 315)=0.01\\
p(90\le 135)=0.20\\
p(225\le x\le 270)=0.60\\
p(315\le x\le 360)=0.06
$$

All the properties of probability distributions then follow naturally.